# While deploying an application I faced this error, can anyone help me

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

error: resource mapping not found for name: "pod-info-deployment" namespace: "development" from "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "app/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

"This is deployment.yaml file which I'm running"

```html
---
apiVersion: app/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pod-info-deployment
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: pod-info
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selectors:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-info # select pods with this label to be managed by the deployment.
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pod-info  # add a new label for each instance of our application that is
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pod-info-container
        image: kimschles/pod-info-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.podIP
```

I was running this  "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml" It return me this why ? -> error: resource mapping not found for name: "pod-info-deployment" namespace: "development" from "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "app/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

Answer (score 2):

There are three mistakes

1. replace "app/v1" with "apps/v1"
2. replace "selectors:" with "selector:"
3. replace "fieldPath: metadata.podIP" with "fieldPath: status.podIP"

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `apiVersion` of the manifest. It should be `apps/v1` not `app/v1`